# Черный экран перед загрузкой приложения Android

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Всем привет!

При загрузке Android приложения, собранного в Unity, перед загрузкой всегда на пару секунд появляется ненавистный чёрный экран. В Unity отключаю Splash Screen и Logo. Пробовал кидать пустую сцену, такой же эффект. Подскажите, кто-нибудь решал такую проблему и если да, то как?

Прикрепляю видео для наглядности (перед отображением красного фона тот самый экран).
https://transfiles.ru/1ixm2

Comment: без какого-либо лога ваш вопрос просто бесполезный

Comment: Какой именно лог поможет?

Comment: Имеется в виду лог с телефона через андроид студию, там логируютса все действия, и возможно будет показана ошибка посмотрите туда.

Comment: А как посмотреть такой лог, если я  собираю проект в Unity? По сути никакой ошибки нет, приложение загружается и работает нормально. Но вот этот чёрный экран.

Comment: adb logcat -b all > log.txt или просто adb logcat > log.txt @DenVebber

Comment: Так же можете скачать Андроид студию и смотреть через неё. А по поводу чёрного екрана возможно у вас игра в одной сцене, и она слишком долго грузиться. Для проверки создайте пустую сцену с канвасом и белой картинкой, что бы было видно как быстро она появится после показал лого юнити (или вашего лого)

Comment: Уже создавал пустую сцену. Такой же эффект)
По идее этот чёрный экран и был Splash Screen из Unity. Сейчас включил его в настройках, заменил на картинку и в файле Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk\res\values\styles.xml поставил <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
Сейчас чёрный экран не отображается.


Может быть кто-то добавлял через styles.xml в Unity картинку? Как это провернуть? Например в android это выглядит так <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>

Comment: Смотрите если у вас проект на андроид то скорее всего там есть манифест, возможно кто-то сделал кастомный манифест. И именно в файле манифеста может быть ссылка на включенный сплеш екран к примеру. И при сборке через гладл юнити как бы мерджит манифесты, и потому если там было написано установить сплеш екран то при слиянии манифестов (один тот что в проекте у вас а второй генерится при билде) у вас будет включен этот самый сплеш екран. Как решение посмотрите манифесны в проекте.